# How to get the id of a database entity with Persistent?

Tags: sql, haskell, persistent

I have a database model, using Persistent like so

```
import           Database.Persist.TH (mkPersist, persistUpperCase,
                                  share, sqlSettings)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings] [persistUpperCase|
Foo
    field1 Int
    field2 Bool
|]
```

And I am able to get an object `foo :: Foo` from the database. I can access the fields with `fooField1 foo :: Int` and `fooField2 foo :: Bool`. And because I use `sqlSettings`, I know there is an `Int64`-representation of a database key the "id" stored with every entity. E.g. when I use `get . toSqlKey :: Int64 -> ...`

Given my `foo :: Foo`, how do I get the `id :: Int64`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Foo` by itself doesn't have an id, since `Foos` can exist outside of the database (before they are written). That's why a select operation for example gives you back a list of Entity, that contains both the key and the object.

See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2/docs/Database-Persist-Types.html#t:Entity

For example, see the yesod book (http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) on fetching from a primary key constraint:

```
personId <- insert $ Person "Michael" "Snoyman" 26
maybePerson <- getBy $ PersonName "Michael" "Snoyman"
case maybePerson of
    Nothing -> liftIO $ putStrLn "Just kidding, not really there"
    Just (Entity personId person) -> liftIO $ print person
```

the return type of getBy is an Entity wrapping both the key (`personId`) and the value (`person`).

Comment: if I don't use `getBy` but e.g. an esqueleto query, I typically use `entityVal` and drop the id ... I just didn't notice.

Comment: For completeness sake: `fromSqlKey . entityKey :: Entity record -> Int64` on an entity retrieved from the database (e.g. `Entity foo`) gives the id.